# Is this valid json data?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The url has following json data:

```
[{ "topic": "cricket",
    "value": "Player [ playerid=123, category=b, high=150, total=2300]",
    "place": "xyz"},
 { "topic": "cricket",
    "value": "Player [ playerid=456, category=c, high=60, total=300]",
    "place": "abc"},
 { "topic": "cricket",
    "value": "Player [ playerid=789, category=a, high=178, total=5300]",
    "place": "bnm"}]
```

I tried online to check whether this is valid json or not through following link: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ it says valid. if it is, how do I access each playerid ?

Comment: It is valid, but `playerid` isn't a field that you've made available. You have `value`, `topic` and `place`.

Comment: It's a valid string. However, `Player [ playerid=123, category=b, high=150, total=2300]` is not a valid JSON expression that had a programmatically accessible `playerid` property - you'd need to parse it.

Comment: Probably valid, but definitely strange.  Looks like Player is an array of objects that's not encoded properly.

Comment: Can't I access playerid ? How do i parse ?
obj.value[0].player.playerid this doesn't seem to work.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

It is valid JSON, but the data about the player is embedded in a random string.  You can do one of two things:

1. Update the service to send back a different, valid JS value, for example:

   ```
   "value": {
     "type": "Player",
     "playerid": 123,
     "category": "b",
     "high": 150,
     "total": 2300
   }
   ```
2. Parse the data in the `value` key yourself:

   ```
   // Simple regex, not really "parsing"
   var playerIdRE = /playerid=(\d+)/i;
   var result = playerIdRE.exec(yourData[0].value);
   // result[0] is the full match, while result[1] is the ID.

   // Or the more complicated version that does full parsing
   var format = /\s*(.*?)\s*\[\s*([^\]]+)\s*\]\s*/gi,
     keyValuePair = /(\w+)=([^,\]]*),?\s*/gi
   function parseComplexDataType(input) {
     var result = format.exec(input),
       typeName = result[1],
       keyValues = result[2],
       returnValue = {};
     if (!typeName) return returnValue;
     returnValue.typeName = typeName;
     input.replace(keyValuePair, function(_, key, value) {
       returnValue[key] = value;
     });
     return returnValue;
   }

   // Usage:
   > parseComplexDataType("Player [ playerid=123, category=b, high=150, total=2300]")
   Object {typeName: "Player", playerid: "123", category: "b", high: "150", total: "2300"}
   ```

Comment: So finally, is it not possible to get playerid ?(I could have done myself if the data is in the mentioned form of yours)

Comment: @user2515138 - it is possible, you just have to go with the second version, or a more complicated version that actually parses out the full data.

Answer (score 0):

For your purposes, it is not valid.  Once the JSON is corrected, you simply need to loop through the array and read each value.

```
var jArray = [{ 
  "topic": "cricket",
  "value": {
    "type": "Player",
    "playerid": 123,
    "category": "b",
    "high": 150,
    "total": 2300
  },
  "place": "xyz"
}, {
...
}]
```

To access the JSON data ...

```
for (var i=0,len=jArray.length; i<len; i++) {
  console.log(jArray[i].topic, jArray[i].value.type);
}
```

Comment: i agree that validity is a formality in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. I check it via: http://jsonlint.com/

Extracting "playerid":

1. Initialise the string to JSONArray.
2. Iterate over each element in the above array.
3. Now, from each element extract "value".
4. Finally, from this string you can get "playerid" by using string methods (see the code below).

Below is the code in Java:

```
ArrayList<String> player_ids = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = "YOUR STRING";
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(s);
for(int i =0; i<ja.length(); i++)
{
   String value = ja.getJSONObject(i).getString("value");
   int start = value.indexOf("=");
   int end = value.indexOf(",");
   String player_id = value.substring(start+1, end);
   player_ids.add(player_id);
}
```

Hope it helps!!